# How does recalling a variable work in a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following method:

```
vendor_orders = VendorOrder.where(id: params[:vendor_order_ids])
orders = Order.find(vendor_orders.pluck(:order_id))
products = Product.joins(:vendor_product).where(vendor_products:{vendor_id: current_user.id }).ids #get all vendor_products that match current_user.vendor
line_items = LineItem.joins(:shop_product).where(cart_id: orders.pluck(:cart_id), fulfillment_status: "processing", shop_products: {product_id: products}).where.not(fulfillment_status: "canceled")
messages = []
n = 0
puts "line items: #{line_items.count}" #puts out 1
line_items.map do |li|
  if li.update_attribute(:fulfillment_status, params[:mass][:fulfillment_status])
    n+=1
  else
    messages << "#{vendor_order.vendor_order_token}"
  end
end
puts "line items2: #{line_items.count}" #puts out 0
if n == line_items.count
  flash.keep[:notice] = "Update for #{vendor_orders.count} order(s) and #{n} product(s) successful"
else
  flash.keep[:notice] = "Failed update for Order: #{messages.join if messages.any?}"
end
puts "line item3 #{line_items.count}" #puts out 0
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to vendor_orders_path }
end
```

The question i have is about the `puts`

When calling `line_items.count` after I update the `line_items` to then not match the variable, does it recall `line_items` from above?

Is this true? I always assumed once something was defined and passed, it would stay at the rate, unless redefined.

Comment: `line_items` is a relation, calling  `line_items.count` executes SQL query with `select count(line_items.*)` and returns its result, so it can obviously change as an effect of some operations you perform in between.

Comment: Hm.  Can I hard define it at the top with `line_items_count = line_items.count`? or is there not way and I should just be redefining with the params i update it to?

Comment: Yes, assigning the result of this method call to some variable is gonna work.

Comment: And BTW you seem to show some lack of understanding of basic concepts in Ruby, so I would put aside Rails for a time and learn Ruby itself.

Comment: This is a mass update method and this is the way I thought of on how I can dynamically show a flash notice.  If you're referring to the question, I assumed methods were done asynchronous.

Comment: I am wondering why you thought the code was bad.  Is there something you would have done differently in any aspect of that method?  I assume it's the way I get to line_items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marek solved the issue by letting me know `.count` is a call to the database which will then call what you defined previously.

To solve this, I just use `line_items_count = line_items.count` and use that above any alterations to check against it.